# pigpio's spi_xfer and spi_open functions

Tags: python, spi, pigpio

In my previous project I have used spidev in order to work with ADC, and in python script I could have:

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
...
adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
```

Now I'm trying to work with *pigpio* library (to avoid the permission demands) but I'm not really sure how to use pigpio's `spi_open` and `spi_xfer` functions. Looks like they take more input arguments than `spi.open` and `spi.xfer2`. Can someone explain to me what these arguments are - in some analogy with my previous approach with spidev? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spi_open](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open)

You only need to specify the channel and bit rate.  The flags should normally be left as 0.  The call returns a handle (a small number >=0) which is passed to the other SPI functions.

h = spi_open(0, 1000000) # get handle for SPI channel 0 at 1000000 bits per second.

[spi_xfer](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_xfer)

Ypu specify the handle (returned by spi_open) and the data to send.  The number of bytes received and the bytes themselves are returned.

adc_channel = 0

count, data = spi_xfer(h, [1,(8+adc_channel)<<4,0])

Send three bytes to the SPI device defined by handle h.  The individual bytes are 1, (8+adc_channel)<<4, and 0.

count will be 3 (the number of bytes received is always the same as the number of bytes send except for errors) and data will be a list of three bytes (data[0], data[1], and data[2]).