# How to read a specific register using spi_xfer from PIGPIO

Tags: pi-3, linux, spi, pigpio

I am building a single channel LoRa gateway using the [RFM95W](http://www.hoperf.com/upload/rf/RFM95_96_97_98W.pdf) module.  I am using this github repo; [single_chan_pkt_fwd](https://github.com/hallard/single_chan_pkt_fwd), as a guide.

However I am not yet using a PCB, even though it is very difficult, but I wanted the practice.  So I removed the male ends off these [jumper wires](https://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J1475.600x480.jpg?ed71e7c29e600ffe80bf66ce0c9522c2) and soldered the copper directly to the module, and connected the female ends to the Pi.

I took extra care not to short the board, and I think I've done it correctly.

To verify that though, I wanted to read the contents of the `RegVersion` register, which is at address `0x42`; see page 85 of the data sheet.

I am using the following python code in terminal (over ssh / [not over network with daemon](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/pigpio.py#L3753) -- not sure if that's causing more problems) for testing:

```
####################################
# running Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+
####################################
import pigpio
import time
pi = pigpio.pi()

# this is the reset pin
pi.set_mode(17, pigpio.OUTPUT)
# this is the DIO0 pin
pi.set_mode(27, pigpio.INPUT)

# reset the board
pi.write(17, 1)
time.sleep(.1)
pi.write(17, 0)

# using main SPI with SPI_CE0_N GPIO08 as NSS
# this is different than the Github example
fd = pi.spi_open(0, 500000)
# file descriptor returns fine

# not sure how to data arg should be
# to read register at address 0x42
#http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_xfer
pi.spi_xfer(fd, ???)
```

I tried to [use value](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_xfer) `b'\x042` for the data arg, but a hex zero was returned for `rx_data`

Of course I googled and found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37847/55838), which is clear, but I didn't quite understand how `[1,(8+adc_channel)<<4,0]` fits into my example.

I did try to chase down the `spiGoS` function in the C code in [pigpio.c](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/pigpio.c#L4395), but I couldn't tell how to go from `SPI_FIFO` to the address I wanted.

In summary: I am wondering how to pass a register address to `spi_xfre` to read the value of the register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 4.3 of the data sheet, of course titled "SPI Interface" has the information I was missing!

> The first byte is the address byte. It is comprises:
>
> A wnr bit,which is 1 for write access and 0 for read access.
>
> Then 7 bits of address, MSB first.

Answer (score 1):

The pigpio Python module actually talks through the daemon regardless of whether it is been run over a network or locally.

The pigpio [Python API](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html).

See Python [spi_xfer](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_xfer).

Note the identifier returned by [spi_open](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open) is a handle not a file descriptor.  I mention this as you can't pass the handle to standard Python file access routines and expect that to work.

Also if you are not using the standard slave select (18 is CE0 on the auxiliary SPI channel) you will have to set it to low (0) before the transfer and set it high (1) afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Joan! But you didn't answer the question! Does that mean b'\\0x42' is the correct value? I will have to check which pin is the standard SS, I thought it was CE0

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know that device.

Comment: So from you responses, I am assuming that whatever the address of the register is, I can use that as the argument?

Comment: Btw I meant to write `GPIO08` not `GPIO18`, hence the `CE0` confusion.